# Do-while loop with tryparse not going to the else statement

Tags: c#, do-while, tryparse

wasn't able to fix my issue through googling around so figured I'd take it here and try my luck. I'm new to c# and writing a program that randomly generates a number and the user gets to guess until it gets it right.Everything runs smoothly but the issue is that if a letter is input instead of a number the else statement isn't triggered and it doesn't give the error message to the user, it just goes to the first if statement instead.

Here is the code, appreciate any help! I hope the formatting is somewhat readable at least.

```
Random slumpat = new Random();
int speltal = slumpat.Next(1, 20);
bool spela = true;
do
{
    Console.Write("\n\tGissa på ett tal mellan 1 och 20: ");
    if (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int tal))
    {
        if (tal < speltal)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\tDet inmatade talet " + tal + " är för litet, försök igen:");
        }
        else if (tal > speltal)
        {
             Console.WriteLine("\tDet inmatade talet " + tal + " är för stort, försök igen:");
        }
        else if (tal == speltal)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\tGrattis, du gissade rätt!");
            Console.ReadLine();
            spela = false;
        }
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("\tDu måste ange en siffra!");
    Console.ReadLine();
} while (spela == true);
```

Comment: Could it have to do with the wrapping on my else statement? I'm getting errors if I try to wrap it.

Comment: The code you have now is working for me. Are you sure this is what you have in your project?

Comment: Hello Connor, yes it does work but the problem is that the else statement isn't picking up non integer inputs, does it do that for you?

Comment: As in, I want it to give the error message listed with "else" when a bad input like "A" is put in by the user

Comment: Yes, the code that is posted here will show "tDu måste ange en siffra!" when you enter a bad input.

Answer (score -1):

As you setting `randomNumber` value as **positive** integer - you can check that user inputed positive number through simple condition `userNumber > 0` right at parsing user input. In case if user inputed a negative number or letter or anything else - `else` statement will be triggered.

Translated your example and edited a bit to make things work. Look at comments to understand what is going on at code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNumber = random.Next(1, 20); // Only positive digits from 1 to 20

    // This variable isn't neccessary. We start loop and running it until user close program manually or loop is breaked from inside.
    // bool play = true;

    do
    {
        Console.Write("Guess a number between 1 and 20: ");

        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int userNumber) && userNumber > 0) // Right here you check that user's guess number is positive integer
        {
            if (userNumber < randomNumber)
                Console.WriteLine("The entered number " + userNumber + " is less than the intended one, please try again!");
            else if (userNumber > randomNumber)
                Console.WriteLine("The entered number " + userNumber + " is greater than intended one, please try again!");
            else if (userNumber == randomNumber)
            {
                // Edited this part to ask user for replay without restarting program
                Console.Write("Congratulations, you guessed it!\nWant play again? (Y/N): ");
                if (Console.ReadLine().ToLower() == "y") // Player want to replay again
                {
                    randomNumber = random.Next(1, 20); // Generate new randomNumber
                    Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 25) + "\n"); // Separator
                }
                else
                    break; // Player doesn't want play again so breaking loop
            }
        }
        else // User inputed negative number or 0 or NaN (Not A Number)
            Console.WriteLine("You must enter a non-negative number!");

    } while (true);

    Console.WriteLine("\nThanks for playing!"); // Don't forget to thank your player!

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close the program...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

That was a simple version which allow user re-enter number intil he guessed right one.

You can make it in **hard mode** so user have some amount of attempts to try guess right number:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random random = new();
    int randomNumber = random.Next(1, 20);

    int maxAttempts = 3; // Declare number or possible attempts for user to guess a number

    do
    {
        if (maxAttempts == 0) // User didn't guess right number for 3 attempts so break the loop
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, but you didn't guessed through 3 attempts.");
            Console.WriteLine("GAME OVER."); // No replay available
            break;
        }

        Console.Write("Guess a number between 1 and 20 (" + maxAttempts + " attempts left): ");

        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int userNumber) && userNumber > 0)
        {
            maxAttempts--; // Subtracting attempts

            if (userNumber == randomNumber)
            {
                Console.Write("Congratulations, you guessed it!\nWant play again? (Y/N): ");
                if (Console.ReadLine().ToLower() == "y")
                {
                    randomNumber = random.Next(1, 20);
                    maxAttempts = 3; // Reset maximum attempts back to 3
                    Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 25) + "\n");
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
            else
            {
                // Do not tell player that he entered a number greater or less than the intended one, it is HARD MODE of your game
                Console.WriteLine("You didn't guess, please try again!");
            }
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("You must enter a non-negative number!");

    } while (true);

    Console.WriteLine("\nThanks for playing!");
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close the program...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```